# Tab Bar Missing when swiped to the right page

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am using Xcode8 with Swift3 to build an iOS app. I have a tab view controller to display different pages. 
In one tab, for example "Home" tab, I have two pages, so I use a segue to direct to the new page as below as well as swipe back to the original page.

However, when I swiped to the new page, the tab manual is gone and when I swiped back, the tab manual is still missing.

```
Import UIKit
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSwipes(sender:)))
    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

}


func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if(sender.direction == .left)
    {
        print("Swipe Left")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRight", sender: self)
    }
}
}
```

as shown in the picture below, when my app move from "first left view" to "first right view" the tab bar in the bottom disappeared.
How could I resolve this problem?

[image: storyboard screen]

Comment: You'd need to post how is configured your storyboard

Comment: Are you using default tab bar ? or you use some third party library ?

Comment: Hi, I am using default tab bar

Comment: You can embed Navigation ViewController or Paging ViewController into your First Left View. and then you can hide the top bar (if you're embeding navigation view controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Segue with identifier "toRight" is actually "presenting"(not pushing into the stack. So, it the reason to hide your TabBar) the "FirstRightView ViewController" why because you don't have NavigationController for the FirstViewController. So it automatically Present's the ViewController.

So,Embed your FirstViewController with NavigationController then it will work's fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. By adding the Navigation Controller, the tab bar is appear. However, when I swiped to the right view, the "swipeToLeft" segue cannot be triggered, my app not able to get back to the left view.

Comment: Eventhough it trigger perform segue it will add the viewController to navigation stack. So, I think there is no need of triggering the backward perform segue(As already it is in stack). Anyway it will provide back button along with swipe also. Try to swipe from the edge it will show your first VC.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me, I am pretty new in IOS. I tried your method with navigation bar, it works. However, the customer requirement doesn't contain a navigation bar. After I hiding the navigation bar, I can't use swipe to go back to the left page. And also, the requirement doesn't say need to swipe from the "edge", user can swipe anywhere to the left page. How should I achieve that?

Comment: Or in this case, a scrollview is a better choice?

Comment: Ok, it's a suggestion instead of using segue to go back you can use popViewController method of UINavigationController. Now replace the code what you have in left Page "handleGesture:" method with "_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)". And give a try for it.

Comment: Then upVote my answer:)

Comment: Sure, accepted and voted, thanks! To be more specific to others, I removed the segue for swipe back in storyboard and add the line of code in the "FirstRightViewController" class - "handleSwipes" function.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
select your view controller see your interface builder

select the checkbox